# Error while copy past data from excel to handsontable grid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal, handsontable

```
>     handsontable.full.js?v=1.2:10476 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
>         at _removeClass (handsontable.full.js?v=1.2:10476)
>         at removeClass (handsontable.full.js?v=1.2:10531)
>         at handsontable.full.js?v=1.2:5426
>         at done (handsontable.full.js?v=1.2:5502)
>         at handsontable.full.js?v=1.2:5517
>         at handsontable.full.js?v=1.2:23966
>         at ColumnSettings.Handsontable.AutocompleteValidator [as validator] (handsontable.full.js?v=1.2:23949)
```

It's working fine when i am pasting 4 to 5 columns but when i trying more than 7 getting above error.previously i tested in tab it's works fine there but when i moved handsontable grid to bootstrap modal getting this error.please help i am trying to understand.

please find below how i created handsontable

```
manualHot = new Handsontable(container, {
              rowHeaders: true,
              colHeaders: true,
              startRows: 100,
              startCols: 125,
             // columns: columns,
              dropdownMenu: true,
              contextMenu: true,
              filters:true,
              manualColumnResize: true,
              height: 500,
              wordWrap:false,
              colWidths: 100,
              rowHeights: 23,
              autoColumnSize: true,
              columnSorting: true,
              fixedRowsTop:1,
              copyable:true,
              sortFunction: function(sortOrder, columnMeta) {
                return function(a, b) {
                    var plugin = manualHot.getPlugin('columnSorting');
                  var sortFunction;                  
                  if (a[0] === 0) {
                    return -1;
                  }                  
                  switch (columnMeta.type) {
                    case 'date':
                      sortFunction = plugin.dateSort;
                      break;
                    case 'numeric':
                      sortFunction = plugin.numericSort;
                      break;
                    default:
                      sortFunction = plugin.defaultSort;
                  }                 
                  return sortFunction(sortOrder, columnMeta)(a, b);
                };
              },
              trimDropdown :false,
              formulas: true,
              cells: function (row, col, prop) {
                    var cellProperties = {};
                    if (row === 0) {
                      cellProperties.type = 'dropdown';
                      cellProperties.source= colHeaderArr;
                      cellProperties.allowInvalid = false;
                    }
                    return cellProperties;
              },
              afterValidate: function (isValid, value, row, prop, source) {
                  if (source === 'loadData' || source === 'internal' ) {
                    return;
                  }                 
                  if (!isValid ) {
                          errorHeader[prop]=headerCols[prop];                       
                      }
              },
            });

              manualHot.addHook('beforeChange', function(changes, source) {         
                  dupheaders=[] 
                  dupheaders.length=0;
                if (source === 'loadData' || source === 'internal' || changes.length > 1) {
                    return;
                }               
                var row = changes[0][0];
                var prop = changes[0][1];
                var newVal = changes[0][3];
                var oldVal=changes[0][2];

                if ( row ===0) {                        
                    headerCols[prop]=newVal;                     
                     var sorted_head = headerCols.slice().sort();                   
                     for (var i = 0; i < headerCols.length - 1; i++) {
                         if (sorted_head[i + 1] == sorted_head[i]) {
                             if(sorted_head[i]){dupheaders.push(sorted_head[i]);}
                         }
                     }
                     if(dupheaders.length>0){                    
                      var errMsg='Duplicate Headers :<br>'+dupheaders;
                      setTimeout(function(){$('#manualDataOnlinePrep-Tab').unblock();},1000);
                      common.showMessage(errMsg, false, "error", "middle-center");
                      } 
                    errorHeader.splice(prop, 1);
                    setColumnType(colProp,prop,newVal, this,txnTypeArr);                   
                }
              }); 
              manualHot.init();

    }


      function setColumnType(columnProp,col,newVal, instance,ddValue) {
          if(newVal === 'Reporting Code Description' )  {
              columnProp[col].type='dropdown';
              columnProp[col].source=ddValue;
          }
          else{
                 if(newVal.match(/^.*Date$/)){
                    columnProp[col].type='date';                
                    columnProp[col].dateFormat=document.getElementById("dateFormat_2").value;           
                    columnProp[col].allowInvalid=true;              
                  }
                 else if (newVal.match(/^.*Amount$/)){
                    columnProp[col].type='numeric';
                    columnProp[col].format=  '[00,00,000].00';  
                    columnProp[col].allowInvalid=false;
                  }  
                 else if (newVal.match(/^.*Rate$/)){                
                    columnProp[col].type='numeric';
                    columnProp[col].format=  '0.[000000]';  
                    columnProp[col].allowInvalid=false;
                  } 
                 else{
                    columnProp[col].type='text';
                 }
             }   
            instance.updateSettings({columns: columnProp},{contextMenu:true}); 
            instance.validateCells(function() {
            instance.render();
            });
          }
```

Comment: Can you share your handsontable configuration ?

Comment: this is not with modal.looks like handsontable have some limit to pasting columns.i created TAB instead of modal but same problem if i increase number of columns. actually how many columns we can copy to handsontable grid?

Comment: With a simple configuration, I'm able to past more than 100 columns of data from Excel to Hansdontable. I'm not sure the problem come from a limitation of handsontable itself but from your configuration. What exactly are you trying to achieve ? I can't fully use your handsontable configuration because some parameter are defined elsewhere in your code (e.g : *colHeaderArr*). Describe your requirements, it will be more simple to give you a working example that way if I can.

Comment: sorry,It a problem with data when copy data from excel getting space end and start of each column values.So drop down not matching with values.